# Opening SharePoint Central Admin throws an error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, configuration, installation

I am getting the following error when trying to access my SharePoint site admin via 
Start > Microsoft Office Server > **SharePoint Central Administration**

```
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.SetHttpParameters(System.String, System.String, UInt32, Byte[] ByRef, Boolean, System.String, UInt32, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ISPManagedObjectFactory)'. 



Stack Trace: 

 [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.SetHttpParameters(System.String, System.String, UInt32, Byte[] ByRef, Boolean, System.String, UInt32, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ISPManagedObjectFactory)'.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetHttpParameters(String bstrHttpMethod, String bstrRequestDigest, UInt32 flags, Byte[]& ppsaImpersonateUserToken, Boolean bIgnoreTimeout, String bstrUserId, UInt32 ulRoleCount, String bstrRoles, Boolean bWindowsMode, Boolean bInvalidateCachedConfigurationProperties, Int32 lAppDomainId, ISPManagedObjectFactory pFactory) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous) +3272
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode) +335
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestNoAuth() +33
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpHandler.get_Hash() +197
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpHandler.get_AppDomainIdHeader() +180
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpHandler.OverrideExecuteUrlPath() +881
   System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +135
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +392
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +263
```

I am using .Net Framework 2.0. Sharepoint 2007. IIS 6.1 (SP1). WS 2008 R2 on x64

Has anyone came across the error? 
Many thanks

Comment: Is this the first install? Did you upgrade or apply patches? What caused this?

Comment: After you ran the SharePoint Product Configuration Wizard, I assume you received a successful message. Do you see any warnings in the logs after running the wizard?

Comment: What happens when you right click the CA site and run as administrator?

Comment: Are you running the latest Service Pack (SP 3) of SP 2007?

Comment: @Mike, Hossein
The error occurred after a failed deployment of an asp.net application which uses SharePoint as its front-end. I rolled back the asp.net earlier version and started to see the error.

I did not touch the GAC or any of the files in the SCA virtual directory either, so I am bit puzzled?

Comment: @Hossein. Running the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard failed with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve my issue I had to repair the SharePoint Server Installation. I followed the steps below:

Go to **Control Panel** > **Programs** > **Programs and Features**

Right click **Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007** and select **Change**.

At the “**Change your installation of Microsoft Office Server 2007**” screen ensure **Repair** option is selected. Click **Continue** and wait till it ends

Restarted my machine et voila everything was working as before.

Answer (score 0):

Rerun the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard again. The Wizard will try to repair your SP installation by adding the missing files.

On the Connect to a server farm screen screen, select Connect to an existing server farm option.